# Website image doesn't show when linking through another site

Tags: html, .htaccess, linkedin-api

I'm linking my website through another site (for example my linkedin page) and for some reason it doesn't show any default image, instead it has the default blank image. Linking other sites, I get it to show correctly. I read somewhere that it has to do with not having my site prefixed with `www.` by default. Is that relevant?

Here is my linked in page: https://www.linkedin.com/in/stefmoreau

As you can see some websites show with images but the last 2 don't. They also happen to not redirect to their `www.` prefixed version when viewing them.

Answer (score 1):

Linkedin uses the Open Graph Protocol to get images. AFAIK it's not related to the "www" part.

Take great care with linkedin: they cache what their bot retrieves, and there's NO refresh for it you can trigger.
Hence, I'd advise to first get it right using e.g. Facebook's OG implementation as they at least have a tool to let you refresh what the crawler fishes up.

- [Linkedin doc](https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/46687/~/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin)
- [Facebook doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters)